# Is using void mandatory for methods which don't return something?

Tags: java, android, database, function, methods

I saw this code somewhere:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBName";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table MyEmployees
                                 ( _id integer primary key,name text not null);";

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Method is called during creation of the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
        Log.w(MyDatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                         "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                         + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyEmployees");
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

As you see `MyDatabaseHelper` method returns nothing *(doesn't return anything)*. So why the author didn't use `void` for that?

Comment: It's called a constructor and it's used for initializing an object (in this case, you want to initialize the database helper with a `Context`). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @nbokmans Ah I see. and can you please tell me what's `long` in this `public long createRecords(String id, String name){ ` ? Is it the type of what the function returns?

Comment: In that case, `long` is the method's return type yes. This resource explains the difference between `fields`, `methods` and `constructors` better: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: `long` is a datatype usually used for whole numbers when they may grow over what an `int` can hold (up to roughly 2 billion (or two thousand million, as I learned it in school)). This is basic Java knowledge, you could probably find it faster in your text book or tutorial than here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a constructor and it's used for initializing an object upon creation (in this case, you want to initialize the database helper with a `Context`). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

A better example to help you understand constructors:

```
public class Person {

    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("My name is %s and I am %d years old", name, age);
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person me = new Person("Niels", 20);
        System.out.println(me);
    }
}
```

When you execute the above code, you will see a message in your console saying `My name is Niels and I am 20 years old`.

As you can see we have created a `Person` object taking a `name` and an `age` parameter.

Comment: You've used `@Override` in a class which isn't extended from any other class .. I think it is impossible. Am I right?

Comment: No. Every class you create implicitly extends the `java.lang.Object` class, which offers some methods such as `toString` and `hashCode`. As per the documentation: "Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.". See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: *Every class you create implicitly extends the `java.lang.Object` class* .. Even those classes that doesn't `extends` anything?

Comment: Yes. That's why I said implicitly. :P

Comment: Ah .. Sorry I don't know English very well, that's why I didn't get your point of *implicitly* .. `;-)`

Comment: And my last question, what's `person` *(with small `p`)* in this: `System.out.println(person);` ?

Comment: Also, it would be much better if you show us the result of your code as a comment under your code `:-)`

Comment: `person` is what I named the variable which holds the `Person` object. You could name that anything you want (assuming it's not an invalid identifier, such as when you start with a number or have a special character).

Comment: First, thank you for appending the result of your code to your answer. Second, also as far as I know, the name of the variable which holds the `Person` object is **`me`**, not `person` ..

Comment: Oh woops, I changed the variable name in one place but didn't in the other. My bad! It should be `me` indeed.

Answer (score 1):

because thats a class constructor!

"When the object is created, Java calls the constructor first. Any code you have in your constructor will then get executed. You don't need to make any special calls to a constructor method - they happen automatically when you create a new object. Constructor methods take the same name as the class."

"If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods (in this case SQLiteOpenHelper), you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super (in this case its own constructor). Consider this class, Superclass:"

Answer (score 1):

because its a class constructor!

Only the class' constructor is a method that don't have any return type. Rest all method should have their return types.

Note: There may be more than one constructor (default & constructor with different parameters).

Answer (score 1):

That method is called a constructor. It has the same name as the class it is in and is called when instantiating the class by calling `new`. And it actually does not return void; it returns the instance of the class it is instantiating.

The class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        // do something, notice the constructor has the name of the class
    }
}
```

Using the class:

```
    MyClass theInstance = new MyClass();
```

See the links in the other answers if you want more information.